# Count query and subquery

Tags: sql

This query gets thread id's which belong to category and returns count of posts which belong to those threads:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM post p 
WHERE p.thread_id IN (SELECT t.id 
                      FROM thread t 
                      WHERE t.category_id = 1);
```

How to make this query also add number of threads (count of subquery) to total count?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) cnt,
    COUNT(DISTINCT p.thread_id) cnt_threads
FROM post p 
WHERE p.thread_id IN (SELECT t.id FROM thread t WHERE t.category_id = 1);
```

Also, using `IN` with a subquery is tricky. If any of the values returned by the subquery is `NULL`, then none of the values will ever match. Your query could be probably be rewritten as:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) cnt,
    COUNT(DISTINCT p.thread_id) cnt_threads
FROM post p 
INNER JOIN thread t ON p.thread_id = t.id AND t.category_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a window function

```
SELECT 
        COUNT(*)  OVER(ORDER BY p.postid) AS CountPosts
    ,   t.CountThreads
FROM 
    post p 
    CROSS APPLY  
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS CountThreads 
        FROM thread t
        WHERE  t.threadid = p.threadid
        AND t.cat=1
    ) t
```